# Live streaming video with overlay on web-page for iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, html, html5-video, http-live-streaming

On the iPad, is it possible to embed live streaming video in a web page *and* put a semitransparent overlay (higher z-index) on top?

Note that in the end I am looking for a solution that also works for desktop browsers at least, and ideally also on mobile devices other than the iPad. By the way, I am happy for suggestions concerning streaming platforms that offer embeddable video-widgets. We don't want to set up our own streaming server for now.